# Unable to find time zone

Tags: influxdb

I always get an error when I try to use `tz()` in my influx-db queries

Simple working query example:

```
> use _internal
> precision rfc3339
> select * from cq limit 2
name: cq
time                 hostname        queryFail queryOk
----                 --------        --------- -------
2018-08-28T13:46:20Z DESKTOP-M60GAEJ 0         0
2018-08-28T13:46:30Z DESKTOP-M60GAEJ 0         0
```

But when I try to use `tz()` as explained in the [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/data_exploration/#the-time-zone-clause), I get an error:

```
> select * from cq tz('America/Chicago') limit 2
ERR: error parsing query: unable to find time zone America/Chicago
```

I've also tried a different order (`tz()` at the end):

```
> select * from cq limit tz('America/Chicago')
ERR: error parsing query: unable to find time zone America/Chicago
```

Also some other timezones (as specified [in the tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones#List)) result in the same error.

I use influx version `1.6.2` on 64-bit Windows 10
I see the same issue in version `1.7.0~n201808280800`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, see: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/10196

Cheers.